# How to use botkit with facebook and wit.ai

Tags: facebook, chatbot, wit.ai, botkit

I am a novice in chatbot development and I would like some help.
While it seems quite simple to connect botkit with facebook messenger and wit.ai in orger to use NLP. I haven't managed to do so. My initial goal is to have a simple conversation like hello-hello but using wit.ai as middleware.
Below I attach the code. What it should do is receive a "hello" message, pass it to wit.ai and then respond "I heard hello!" as a reply (without using wit at this stage). Instead I just receive

debug: RECEIVED MESSAGE
debug: CUSTOM FIND CONVO XXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
debug: No handler for message_received

after every message I send to facebook messenger bot. In wit it seems like I am getting the messages since I receive messages in my inbox to update the intents. 
If there is any code much simpler than the one below I would be very happy to have it so that I can start with something much simpler :).
Thanks

```
<pre><code>
if (!process.env.page_token) {
console.log('Error: Specify page_token in environment');
process.exit(1);
}

if (!process.env.page_token) {
console.log('Error: Specify page_token in environment');
process.exit(1);
}

if (!process.env.verify_token) {
console.log('Error: Specify verify_token in environment');
process.exit(1);
}

if (!process.env.app_secret) {
console.log('Error: Specify app_secret in environment');
process.exit(1);
}

var Botkit = require('./lib/Botkit.js');
var wit = require('./node_modules/botkit-middleware-witai')({
token: process.env.wit,
minConfidence: 0.6,
logLevel: 'debug'
});
var os = require('os');
var commandLineArgs = require('command-line-args');
var localtunnel = require('localtunnel');

const ops = commandLineArgs([
  {name: 'lt', alias: 'l', args: 1, description: 'Use localtunnel.me to make your bot available on the web.',
  type: Boolean, defaultValue: false},
  {name: 'ltsubdomain', alias: 's', args: 1,
  description: 'Custom subdomain for the localtunnel.me URL. This option can only be used together with --lt.',
  type: String, defaultValue: null},
]);

if(ops.lt === false && ops.ltsubdomain !== null) {
console.log("error: --ltsubdomain can only be used together with --lt.");
process.exit();
}

var controller = Botkit.facebookbot({
debug: true,
log: true,
access_token: process.env.page_token,
verify_token: process.env.verify_token,
app_secret: process.env.app_secret,
validate_requests: true, // Refuse any requests that don't come from FB on your receive webhook, must provide FB_APP_SECRET in environment variables
});

var bot = controller.spawn({
});

controller.setupWebserver(process.env.port || 3000, function(err, webserver) {
controller.createWebhookEndpoints(webserver, bot, function() {
    console.log('ONLINE!');
    if(ops.lt) {
        var tunnel = localtunnel(process.env.port || 3000, {subdomain: ops.ltsubdomain}, function(err, tunnel) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                process.exit();
            }
            console.log("Your bot is available on the web at the following URL: " + tunnel.url + '/facebook/receive');
        });

        tunnel.on('close', function() {
            console.log("Your bot is no longer available on the web at the localtunnnel.me URL.");
            process.exit();
        });
    }
});
});

controller.middleware.receive.use(wit.receive);

controller.hears(['hello'], 'direct_message', wit.hears, function(bot, message) {
   bot.reply(message, 'I heard hello!');
 });

function formatUptime(uptime) {
var unit = 'second';
if (uptime > 60) {
    uptime = uptime / 60;
    unit = 'minute';
}
if (uptime > 60) {
    uptime = uptime / 60;
    unit = 'hour';
}
if (uptime != 1) {
    unit = unit + 's';
}

uptime = uptime + ' ' + unit;
return uptime;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a few conversations in Wit.ai beforehand so for example *hello there* and highlight the *hello* in that statement as something like, `greetings`.

Now i'm not sure what your intents are called in wit.ai but in your statement `controller.hears(['hello']` you're actually listening to the wit.ai intents. So in the example i mentioned above, we'd be using `hears(['greetings'])` since that's the intent in wit.ai.

Also, instead of using `direct_message` use `message_received` this is what it should look like:

```
controller.hears(['hello'], 'message_received', wit.hears, function(bot, message) {
   bot.reply(message, 'I heard hello!');
 });
```

If you're struggling tracking down the problem you can stick a console statement in your controller so something like `console.log("Wit.ai detected entities", message.entities);` and see what you get back from that.

Let me know if you're still having any issues :)